# Run a Linux shell script using a file inserted by the user in Python

Tags: python, linux, input, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I am trying to run a ffprobe command using a pre-defined by the user input file in Python. And then I will use the generated file by this command to report some parameters in a more organized view. My code is:

```
import subprocess
import json

cmd = "ffprobe -v quiet -print_format -show_format -show_streams /path/to/input/file.mp4 > output.json" 
subprocess.call(cmd.split())

with open('output.json') as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
        json_data.close()
        d = float((data["streams"][0]["duration"]))
        t = (data["streams"][0]["time_base"])
        fps = [float(x) for x in t.split('/')]
        print "==========================General=========================="
        print "Name of the File: %s" %(data["format"]["filename"])
        print "Duration: %.2f minutes" %(d/60)
        print "Frame Rate: %d fps" %fps[1]
        print "Bitrate: %.2f Mbps" %(float(data["format"]["bit_rate"])/1000000)
```

I was thinking to use: `input_file = ("Please enter the path to your input file: ")` and then use the input_file in the ffprobe command on the second line of my code. But I am not sure how I can do it within the quotes. Please also note that the file name should also include an extension like input.mp4.

Answer (score 0):

Shell redirection (`>`) will only work when `shell=True` is passed to `subprocess.call()`. Generally you should avoid doing that, specially if you take user input as part of the executed command, in which a case you need to make sure that the user input is properly escaped, e.g. by using `shlex.qutoe()`.

Instead of using redirection in the shell you can open the file to write in python and pass it as `stdout`, or if you don't need the file you can use `subprocess.check_output()` instead of `subprocess.call()`:

```
input_filename = raw_input("Please enter the path to your input file: ")
cmd = ['ffprobe', '-v', 'quiet', '-print_format', 'json', '-show_format', '-show_streams',
       input_filename]

returned_data = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
data = json.loads(returned_data.decode('utf-8'))    # assuming the returned data is utf-8 encoded

...
```

Or the same with using a file to write to:

```
input_filename = raw_input("Please enter the path to your input file: ")
cmd = ['ffprobe', '-v', 'quiet', '-print_format', 'json', '-show_format', '-show_streams',
       input_filename]

with open('output.json', 'wb') as outfile:
    subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=outfile)

with open('output.json', 'r') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)

...
```

In this case the input filename doesn't need to be quoted because it is not interpreted by a shell.

Comment: thanks for the hints, but it appears that both of your suggestions are returning syntax error. "Invalid Syntax"

Comment: Did you copy this into a file or just paste it in an interactive interpreter? There shouldn't be a syntax error, but when pasting to the interpreter certain blocks require to be terminated by an empty lline, reformatted accordingly. Also if you paste the next line after `raw_input` will be used and can mess up things. Also I've changed `-print_format` to `-print_format json`, as that is probably what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import json

input_file = raw_input("Please enter the input file path: ")

returned_data = subprocess.check_output(['ffprobe', '-v', 'quiet', '-print_format', 'json', '-show_format', '-show_streams', input_file])
data = json.loads(returned_data.decode('utf-8'))
```